# Is it possible to retrieve an 8 digit number from the database using 6 digits

Tags: sql, node.js, math, cryptography

I have a unique 8-digit number generated for each user in the database as follows:

a 3-digit prefix | any number btw 01 & 99 | a 3-digit number generated sequentially.

For example: 234 | 74 | 216 ==> 23474216

Because I want the user to easily remember this number, I intend to issue just 6 digits out of the 8 digits to the user. For example, using the number 23474216 above, the user gets 234742.

Where the problem lies is that the user must rely on this 6 digit alone to gain access into the system. NO passwords.

So how can I match the 6 digit number to the correct 8 digit number in the database ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so 23474216 and 23474200 will gain access?

Answer (score 0):

giving example

```
Declare @p int = 23474216

select 
      @p as [number]
    , @p/100 as [short] -- because it is int type it will drop decimals
    -- if you have type string - use Substring()
    , Substring('23474216', 1, 6) as [string value]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I encountered with this approach is that the short & string value will be the same for 23474216,  23474218, ... because the last 3 digits start with number 2

Comment: @twinsmaj . . . Hence, you cannot do what you want to do.  You have collisions.